# I have a groovy utils file with a few methods in it how can one method call another

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to have a single .groovy file that has some utility functions defined and have one of those functions call another in that file?

note: for context, this is being used for Jenkins Pipeline library under vars folder. I wanted to have a function used for param validation call another function in the same groovy script file.

i.e. have the someFunction make use of the doSomething function, some pseudo code below.

```
//utils.groovy

def doSomething(def a) {
   def aPrime = a
   if (a == 'somethingSpecial') {
     //handle it
     //some logic goes here 
     aPrime = b
   }
   return aPrime
} 

def someFunction(def x) {
    y = doSomething(x);
    more stuff.. using y
    return someResult
}

def dodad() {
  ...
} 

def whatsIt(){ 
  ...
}
```

In my actual code I get error like `No signature of method: groovysh_evaluate.myCommonFunct() is applicable for argument types: () values: []`

Comment: This is a typical error message by Groovy, which is basically saying "you try to call something, which does noch exists".

Apparently there was no argument given to the function, so that might be an issue.

It might also help to call `this.myCommonFunct()` or to make sure that `myCommonFunct()` is defined before any method using it, for this is a script and not a class.

Comment: To me it looks like you have a different issue than it looks to you in the first place. In groovy it perfectly possible what you’re asking. Since you’re mentioning Jenkins Pipeline we’d need to see the Pipeline script to help. Must be something wrong there. Where’s myCommonFunct() defined?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind this does work.
I got the error when I tried to run the contents of the file locally in groovysh. But no errors when it ran in the Jenkins pipeline